# React Native Android Build Failed

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a React Native Android build, but I am facing an issue and the build is failing due to the error mentioned below[image]. However, when I try to build the Android build using the same project but on a **different computer,** it always works and builds successfully.

Terminal output

> Task :react-native-community_slider:generateReleaseRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_slider:generateReleaseRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_slider:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 22s
22 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 19 up-to-date
mashoodali@Mashoods-MacBook-Pro android %